# How to handle precision problems with the correct terminology

Tags: floating-point

I'm writing a math library and I've encountered trouble with floating point imprecision. I want to know if there are any standard workarounds that are used often. I have doubts about my current method and my lack of knowledge and terminology when it comes to these floating point errors emphasizes the doubt.

Specifically, if I want to check the equality of two floats `a` and `b`, instead of `a == b`, I resort to doing a check  `abs(a - b) < precision` where `precision` is a global variable that can be set by the user.

The issue is that I feel like exposing `precision` to the user is just passing on the issue instead of solving it. I'd prefer to have the `precision` as a constant, but I do not know of any way to find a value aside from performing random tests and using an arbitrary value that works in most cases.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: There is no answer to this as different use cases have different requirements.

Comment: A precision value also doesn't scale well.  For example, within 0.01 is great for certain numbers but with large numbers, like 1e70, won't work and for small numbers like 1e-70 also won't work. Maybe what you really want is something like within an [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), which is a varying magnitude depending on the exponents involved — the idea is to get within some range of the last or last few digits of the binary value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison

Comment: @PhilipKendall I understand. Thank you Erik Eidt and Ewan for the references, though! It's a good starting point.

Comment: "exposing precision to the user is just passing on the issue instead of solving it" - consider that this might be *exactly* what you should do; you can't anticipate the details of somebody else's use case - allow your users to specify the precision themselves. Just don't do it as a global, make it an optional parameter.

Comment: My thought is, since floats by nature lose precision with magnitude, make the `precision` be relative to the magnitude of larger of the 2 numbers, instead of a fixed amount.

Comment: Canonical read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: As a library writer, lets say you provide a generic 'InRange' function, it is not a bad idea to pass the issue to the users of the library since you may not know the data range of the inputs and the precision in this range. What you can do is to make sure that your APIs work as expected with various normal and abnormal (e.g. Nan, Inf) inputs.

Comment: Ruby's `Minitest` library (gem) is an interesting point of comparison. It has both [`assert_in_delta`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions#assert_in_delta-instance_method) (checks the value has an absolute error less than "delta") _and_ [`assert_in_epsilon`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions#assert_in_epsilon-instance_method) (checks that the value has a relative error less than the "epsilon"). Interestingly, both have have a default value for the allowable error, despite it only really making sense for the epsilon.

Comment: (1) It cannot be a constant - each mathematical formula, and each numerical method or algorithm have their own epsilon; (2) furthermore a result's uncertainty partly depends on the input's uncertainty; (3) Generally speaking, tolerance can be specified as either absolute or relative; (4) for matrices, "condition number" is used to predict how sensitive a matrix is to errors.

Answer (score 4):

The fixed comparison you suggested is feasible,
but works best when we know the tested values
will fall within anticipated ranges that are not too broad.
If they could span many octaves (many logarithmic decades)
then your users will be much better off with examining
[relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error).
That's the terminology you're looking for.

There's a whole
[numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis)
literature on the topic, which might consume multiple
semesters of undergraduate study.
Cheat sheet: subtracting quantities of similar magnitude is trouble.
But there's lots of details.

The advice that your users perhaps will really want relates to
[condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number),
sometimes informally referred to as the "stiffness" of a problem.
If users are submitting ill-conditioned problems to your library,
then they should have reduced expectations about precision,
and you may be in a position to offer such feedback.
Techniques such as Lagrangian multipliers,
or solving a dual problem,
can sometimes let us cast the original problem in a different way
so it has improved conditioning.

Returning error bars to your caller might be helpful.
One approach to this is very simple:

- choose some small Δ
- solve f(x - Δ), f(x), and f(x + Δ)
- use the differences between those solutions to advise your caller of the answer's likely precision

Answer (score 2):

**Floating point precision is a very difficult problem**, even if you can statically analyze all the source code of your library (and its direct and indirect dependencies).

And [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) applies to this issue. In general getting a reliable bound on rounding errors of an arbitrary code is (probably) undecidable, or at least a very hard problem.

> Specifically, if I want to check the equality of two floats a and b, > instead of a == b, I resort to doing a check abs(a - b) < precision > where precision is a global variable that can be set by the user.

Probably a check like `abs(a - b) / (abs(a) + abs(b)) < precision` when `a` and `b` are not bitwise equal makes better sense.

If your library is coded in C, consider writing your [GCC compiler plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (perhaps reusing some open source code borrowed from [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon)) to analyze or prove (or estimate rounding errors in) your C code with the C code of the user base.

Read more about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (it has NaNs...)

Answer (score 1):

More important than checking precision is to make calculations precise in the first place.

Errors are relative to the size of the result. So adding up terms from smallest to largest has smaller error. Calculating two large values and then their difference gives you large relative error. A bit of mathematics often helps, like replacing sqrt(x+1) -sqrt(x) with 1 / (sqrt(x+1) + sqrt(x)).

Answer (score 0):

Re terminology. The word *precision* is often confused with accuracy. In your case you may want to refer to precision as either float (32bit IEEE) precision *representation* or double-precision (64bit) representation. For each, you can then define a minimum *accuracy* value for making such comparisons. In this way, you have clear terminology for saying what you mean and a clear strategy for defining the minimum accuracy for each precision.

Another aspect of this problem is scaling, as mentioned already. If you want to support motion over the domain of the data, with consistent accuracy, then it is possible to achieve invariance (or close to) to scale by using a floating origin. e.g., always set the floating origin to the minimum of a, b, before performing any calculations/logic. This enables greater accuracy because the resolution of floating point values is highest near the origin.

An example of achieving extreme scale (Solar System) with single precision numbers is here: https://youtu.be/_04gv3CnjDU.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed "near" comparison is one approach, but is has its own issues.

Basically, the amount of the precision of a floating point number is not a fixed value, which means that different sizes of numbers have different amounts of error.  A number to the power of 100 for example, has a much larger error range than a number to the power of -100.  Your simplistic solution is a good "first" approach, but it won't work well outside of a narrow range of values.

In addition, error on a number should be tracked through the computation.  If I add 20 numbers together, the error range isn't constant, and if I multiply 20 numbers together, the error range doesn't grow linearly.

The real answer to all of these questions is "measurement error analysis", but it's a non-useful answer because in effect, you are asking a question about measurement error analysis.

Assuming you believe the inputted value is 100% correct, then you can automatically know the error of the error of the floating point representation.  This error is basically the distance to the next valid floating point number.

The first bit (bit 0) of a floating point number is the sign bit (0 = positive, 1 = negative).  This has nothing to do with distance, so we skip it.

The next 8 bits (bit 1-9) is the exponent of the number, in 2's complement form.  This provides a range of -128 to 127 for the exponent.

The remaining 23 bits is the fractional portion of the number's mantissa.  Every non-zero number in binary eventually has a 1, and the 23 bits represent every bit after that initial 1.  For you to become familiar with these numbers, you need to realize that these are bits representing fractions, so the first bit is 1/2, the next 1/4, and so on.

This means that the 23 bit is 1/8388608 of the value of the "1" bit, and the error is (+ or -)(1/8388608)^(your float's power).

Adding two numbers together is (A + B), but as we have errors, it is (A + err(a) + B + err(b)), this results in the answer's error growing (A + B) with err(a)+err(b).  Note that err(a) and err(b) are "plus or minus" values, so the error range is "the smallest err(a) + the smallest err(b) to the largest err(a) + the largest err(b)).

Likewise, when multiplying you are really multiplying (A + err(a))(B + err(b)), leading to an error of B(err(a)) + A(err(b)) + (err(a))(err(b)).  Again, this will have to be done with each err(x) being plus or minus, so and then capturing the output of the error in maximum upper and lower bounds).  Similar computations can be done for division (A + err(a))/(B + err(b)).

So, if you want true error tracking through your computations, it won't be enough to just limit you errors to the inputted values, you will also have to follow them through each computation the system makes.

True error analysis is quite laborious, so much of the world assumes the errors won't accumulate to a significant value sufficient to alter the result.  When you get 'to the next layer' of the field, you start to apply statistical tools to the error, often applying a statistical distribution to the initial error of a measurement and then tracking the error distribution fields through the computations.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there are any standard workarounds that are used often.

Remember, the type is call **floating**-point.
[number's radix point can "float" anywhere to the left, right, or between the significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

---

Any form of of rating the *error* of `a, b` is subject to the particular needs of code.  The below uses a general discussion.

Floating point values are generally overall distributed logarithmically.  That implies the *error* between `a, b` is assessed as `(a-b)/max_magnitude(a, b)`.  Then the error of 1500, 3000 is like the error to 0.00015, 0.00030.

Yet within a power-of-2, floating point values are distributed linearly.  That implies the *error* between `a, b` is assessed as `(a-b)/floor(log2(max_magnitude(a, b)))`.  Then the error of 2.100, 2.200 is like the error to 2.800, 2.900.

Both approaches have trouble near [sub-normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) (due to reduced precision), zeros (division by 0), and infinities.

A 3rd, and recommended approach, is to consider each floating point value as an indexed value. Consider all possible positive `float` values (+0.0 ... Infinity) are ordered and indexed 0, 1, 2, ... N.  Negative values are indexed -0, -1, -2, ... -N.  Then the *error* between `a, b` is then `index(a) - index(b)`.  The difference is related to the [unit in the last place (ULP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

This allows for a consistent *error* measurement across the entire ordered `float` range.  See below code.

---

Math functions like `sin(x)`, `sqrt(x)`, `log(x)` are often rated as if the
`x` was exact and the `y = f(x)` (with is finite precision) is rated against the *mathematical* f(x) with it infinite precision.  This *error* is rated in a like manner as if the math result may exist as a fractional index between two `float` indexes.  Combined with ULP, we can say the *error* of a good `sqrt(x)` versus √x is at most 0.5 ULP.  Good implementations of transcendental functions line `sin()`, `log()` have an error < 1.0 ULP.

---

```
// Return the indexed absolute difference of 2 float values.
// Overlay a float and access it as an integer to determine its "index".
// Take advantage the + ascending float values, 
//   when examined as integers are sequenced in ascending integer order.
// Assumes floating-point endian is like integer endian.
// Not valid for not-a-numbers.

unsigned long ULP_diff(float x, float y) {
  assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));
  union {
    float f;
    int32_t ll;
    uint32_t ull;
  } ux, uy;
  ux.f = x;
  uy.f = y;
  if (ux.ll < 0) {
    ux.ll = INT32_MIN - ux.ll;
  }
  if (uy.ll < 0) {
    uy.ll = INT32_MIN - uy.ll;
  }
  unsigned long diff;
  if (ux.ll >= uy.ll) {
    diff = ux.ull - uy.ull;
  } else {
    diff = uy.ull - ux.ull;
  }
  return diff;
}
```